# Probability function question

Tags: probability

my question is:
Given this function -

[image]

When A and B are Permanent and $E(x) = 4.4$.
I need to find $E[(2x-1)^2]$

Why do I need A and B for? Can't I just put 4.4 inside the new formula ($(2x-1)^2$)?

Answer (score 3):

$$\mathbb{E}[(2X-1)^2] = 4 \mathbb{E}[X^2] + 1 - 4\mathbb{E}[X].$$
You can substitute $\mathbb{E}[X]=4.4$, but in order to find $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ you need to find $A$ and $B$ first.

Comment: Can I say this is discrete uniform distribution? and to calculate them by the formula (a+b)/2?

Comment: No. It is not a discrete uniform distribution unless $A=B$, which is not the case.
You need to use that
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = 1A + 2A + 3A + 4B + 5B$$
and that
$$A + A + A + B + B = 1$$
this gives you two equations with two unknowns. Solve it for A and B.

Comment: Thank you! So I solved it for A and B and got A=0.48 and B=0.013. Then I solved like that $E[X^2]$=$(1A)^2+(2A)^2+(3A)^2+(4B)^2+(5B)^2$ and got 9.448. Now I can put it all in the formula.

Comment: No problem. I believe you swapped A and B, it should be $A=0.013$ and $B=0.48$. Also:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 1^2 A + 2^2 A + 3^2 A + 4^2 B+ 5^2 B$$